# My onItemclick function is not working in text to speech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am fetching data from database to list view having content and an Button(Text to speech)conversion.In my listview that button is showing properly and the clickable function is also working audio is not coming,the text to speech audio function is not working properly.

`Mainactivity.java`

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item); 

            mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            mDbHelper.open();
             Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
             if(projectsCursor.getCount()>0)
               {
               fillData(projectsCursor);

               Log.i("filling", "...");
               }
               else
               {
                    new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
               }


            //lv1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);   
            //lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);



            btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
            btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

            myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);

    }



        private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
                Dialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                /*mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this); // initialize mDbHelper before.
                mDbHelper.open();
                Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
                if(projectsCursor.getCount()>0)
                {
                fillData(projectsCursor);
                }*/
                for(int i=0; i<ID.size(); i++){
                    mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                     mDbHelper.open();
                     mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(ID.get(i),TITLE.get(i),CONTENT.get(i),COUNT.get(i)));
                     }
                Dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                getData();
                return null;
            }

        }

        public void getData() {
              try
              {
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.18:3000/api/v1/posts.json");
          // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     

          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
          HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
          String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
           Log.i("................",_response);
          httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
          JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");//(url);
              for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                  JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                  String id = c.getString("id");
                  String title = c.getString("title");
                  String  content = c.getString("content");
                  String  count = c.getString("count");
                  ID.add(id);
                  TITLE.add(title);
                  CONTENT.add(content);
                  COUNT.add(count);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           private void fillData(Cursor projectsCursor) {
               //mDbHelper.open();   

               if(projectsCursor!=null)
               {
               String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
               int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};
                dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                 this, R.layout.activity_row, 
                 projectsCursor, 
                 from, 
                 to,
                 0);
                setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                final ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id) {                    
                       if(arg1.getId()== R.id.btnaudioprayer && arg1.isClickable() ){


                             btnaudioprayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer);

                                   txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,txtText .getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           speakOut();

                        }    
                    }        
                }); 




               }else
               {
                   Log.i("...........","null");
               }

           }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
            if (tts != null) {
                tts.stop();
                tts.shutdown();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void onInit1(int status) {

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                } else {
                    btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);
                    speakOut();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            }

        }

        private void speakOut() {

            String text = txtText.getText().toString();

            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
```

I followed this link for text to speech http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/   i download the source code its working nice,while using that code in my listview,that function is not working properly.